# If else usage for Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 3E
SET A111="Documents and Settings"
SET A222=Users
SET /P PC=Enter Computer IP or HostName: 

@echo Opening Remote Folder....
if exist "" "\\%PC%\C$\"%A111%" (start "" "\\%PC%\C$\"%A111%") else (start \\%PC%\C$\%A222%)
PAUSE
```

Hi, I made a batch file to open some remote folders but there is a mistake I didn't notice.

After entering IP; I want to open, If there is remote "Documents and Settings" folder.
But If there is no "Documents and Settings", I want to see "Users" folder.

Where is the error I make?

Thank you in advance....

Comment: Vista and later `start shell:UserProfiles`

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist "" "\\%PC%\C$\"%1%" (start "" "\\%PC%\"%1%") else (start \\%PC%\C$\%2%)
```

um - no.

```
SET "D1=Documents and Settings"
SET "D2=Users"
if exist "\\%PC%\C$\%D1%" (start "" "\\%PC%\"%D1%") else (start "" "\\%PC%\C$\%D2%")
```

(untested)

You can't (easily) access user-variables that start with a numeric because batch assumes that %n (where n is 0..9) is a command-line parameter.

If exist "" means "if a file named "" exists` - er, what?

The original `\\%PC%...` had unbalanced quotes.

START has a quirk where the first quoted string with which it is provided is the window title, so you need to make a quoted parameter to `start` explicit. Empty is good. Another string may be useful - your choice.

Comment: Both of your codes didnt work...! At least my code can open one of the folders ... :(

Comment: @monacraft : your response was posted 3 minutes before mine. The explanation of why the problem is occurring is different. You corrected your solution about 1 minute after I'd posted mine - you changed the quoting on the variables and discovered the spurious double-quote. Near-simultaneous posts are a fact of life.

Comment: @serdar: Well, we now have three similar solutions from people with experience in batch-file problems. Do you believe that we all sit here, waiting breathlessly for your "error report?" If you don't like the responses, ask for your money back.

Comment: +1, I am tired of people expecting results while they post away with *attitude*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 3E
SET d=Documents and Settings
SET u=Users
SET /P PC=Enter Computer IP or HostName: 

@echo Opening Remote Folder....
if exist "\\%PC%\C$\%d%" (start "" "\\%PC%\%d%") else (start "" "\\%PC%\C$\%u%")
PAUSE
```

You problem was with:

```
if exist "" "\\%PC%\C$\"%1%" (start "" "\\%PC%\"%1%") else (start \\%PC%\C$\%2%)
REM      ^- Why is this "" there?
```

I also replaced `%1%` and `%2%`, in case of confusion with `%1` and `%2` parameters. PLease use atleast one letter in your variable names.

Mona.

Comment: No I'm talking about the double quotes before the Path tree. Look at my edit @serdar.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions 

    COLOR 3E

    SET "A111=Documents and Settings"
    SET "A222=Users"

    SET "PC="
    SET /P "PC=Enter Computer IP or HostName: "

    if defined PC (
        echo Opening Remote Folder....
        if exist "\\%PC%\C$\%A111%\" (
            start "" "\\%PC%\C$\%A111%"
        ) else (
            start "" "\\%PC%\C$\%A222%"
        )
    )

    PAUSE
```

Well, there is no difference between this code and the Magoo or Monacraft answers, just all the parts joined. Quoting corrected, aditional quotes removed, variable names corrected, ...

Comment: It opens only Documents and Settings folder. But It doesnt open Users folder when there is no Documents and Settings...